# Data Scraping Python - Get a tag in a href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am practicing data scraping using BeautifulSoup in Python. Here, I am trying to get the store name, phone number and address of stores on Casey's. I got the store and phone number, but couldn't get the address. Here is the element I am working on:

[image: HTML]

I have two questions:
- How can I get the address from the div `address` while ignoring the `openingSoon` span
- How can I get the address from a href's `data-address` tag?

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you show your code ? how did you try this

Comment: Hello, I posted my code so far in the next comment

Answer (score 0):

put this code after `store = store.string`

```
address_div = chosen.find('div',{'class':'address'})
address = address_div.text
phone = address_div.find('a').text
data_from_d_address = chosen.find('a', {'class': 'myCaseysLink'}).attrs['data-address']

print(address, phone, store, data_from_d_address)
```

**Output**

```
address - '302 SE 7TH AVEGRAND RAPIDS, MN 55744(218) 327-5321ORDER ONLINE'

phone - '(218) 327-5321'

store - 'MN GRAND RAPIDS'

data-address - '302 SE 7TH AVE GRAND RAPIDS,MN 55744'
```